# how can I get unique ip addresses from /var/log/auth.log?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, awk

How do I only show the unique IP addresses in /var/log/auth.log ?
I have a server getting hit constantly, and while I have set up fail2ban, the requests keep coming. So I started writing to ISPs to get the accounts shutdown, which might help a little, but there are so many attacks.... Anyway,

I used this command to sort the hits from today:
$`grep -e 'ruser \| rhost' auth.log | grep -e 'Jun 9' | sort -k 14 | less`
its thousands of attacks... or brute force attempts.

Heres some relivent lines from auth.log:

```
...
Jun  9 10:08:35 nan sshd[23397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53
Jun  9 10:08:51 nan sshd[23401]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53
Jun  9 10:09:07 nan sshd[23428]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53
Jun  9 10:01:59 nan sshd[23216]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:02:52 nan sshd[23238]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:03:08 nan sshd[23246]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:03:40 nan sshd[23256]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:04:14 nan sshd[23270]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:04:31 nan sshd[23276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:05:23 nan sshd[23298]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:05:55 nan sshd[23315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:06:49 nan sshd[23343]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:07:47 nan sshd[23375]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:08:02 nan sshd[23383]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:09:47 nan sshd[23440]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:10:02 nan sshd[23444]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=root
Jun  9 10:09:27 nan sshd[23436]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.109.161.53  user=sshd
Jun  9 05:27:00 nan sshd[20293]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.134.44.86
....
```

I would like to make a list of the unique IP addresses in auth.log.

I tried using `gawk -F: '{ print $14 }' auth.log | uniq -c`

but I guess I'm doing something wrong.
I just want a sorted list of IP addresses from today.
how do I do that?

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but in response to your statement of "I have a server getting hit constantly, and while I have set up fail2ban, the requests keep coming", **this is The Current Standard Traffic on the Internet**.  If your system is Internet facing, **you will be bombarded repeatedly by service scanners, brute forcers, etc.** on your network, and though fail2ban works, you will **NEVER** cease to see these requests.  The only way to protect yourself is proper server hardening to prevent password bruteforce.

Answer (score 6):

`uniq` only detects *adjacent* duplicates - you'd need to sort first

```
awk '{print $14}' auth.log | sort | uniq
```

or use the `sort` command's own `-u` option

```
awk '{print $14}' auth.log | sort -u
```

or (since you're already using `awk`)

```
awk '!seen[$14]++ {print $14}' auth.log
```

(The `rhost=` entry is the 14th whitespace delimited field - no need for `-F:`)

Comment: Or maybe  `awk -F'[= ]' '/ruser/ && /rhost/ { print $21 }' auth.log | sort -u` to get IPs only with conditions.

Answer (score 3):

#### With `grep`

I see you're struggling a bit with `grep` matching patterns as you appear to need to match some patterns before printing unique IPs ... So, ...:

I would use `grep`'s option `-o` to only print the matched part and enable [Perl style regular expressions](https://www.pcre.org/pcre2.txt) with `-P` and use:

- `Jun` to match `Jun` and then ...
- `\s+` to match one or more spaces and then ...
- `9` to match `9` and then ...
- `.*` to match anything until ...
- `ruser=` is matched and then ...
- `.*` to match anything until ...
- `rhost=` is matched and then ...
- exclude all the above from printing with Perl's `\K` and then ...
- match an IP with `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` where `\d+` matches one or more digits and `\.` matches a literal dot and then ...
- pipe the output to `sort -u` to print only unique IPs like so:

```bash
grep -oP 'Jun\s+9.*ruser=.*rhost=\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' auth.log | sort -u
```

#### With `gawk`

Or since you appear to have [GNU AWK](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gawk.1.html) installed, you can do it all(*including sorting ... utilizing [Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)*) with `gawk` like so:

```bash
gawk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "[= ]*"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}

/Jun\s+9/ && /ruser/ && /rhost/ {
    a[$18]++
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        printf "%s\n", i
    }
}' auth.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ egrep -o '[1-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[1-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[1-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[1-2]?[0-9][0-9]?' /var/log/auth.log \
|sort -u
```

I made up the regex pattern, but any regex pattern that matches IP address (there are lots online) should be allowed.

Useful for searching any logs for IP addresses.

Raffa's answer is a bit cleaner, though the first digit in each segment of an IP can only a 1 or 2. (ignoring IPv6 addresses).